# How preserve and keep timestamp of original modified date for file when uploading to Amazon S3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, timestamp

Is there any way either in Java or using s3cmd to keep and preserve the modified date on the file as opposed to the LastModified Amazon sets with sysdate when you actually upload the file to S3 ?

Amazon S3 seems to use the upload timestamp as the LastModified on the file, and not the original file date/timestamp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, S3 isn't storing "files" as you think of them on a filesystem.  You're giving it a sequence of bytes for it to store.  The source of that data can be a file, but it could also be a random stream of data generated by any data source.  That data can have metadata.  One piece of metadata that comes back in the GET Object request is Last-Modified, and S3 decides this for you.

But there's no reason you can't add your own custom headers and preserve whatever metadata you'd like:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

Specifically see "x-amz-meta-".  You can have something like x-amz-meta-what-i-think-last-modified-should-be

Answer (score 0):

This would really be a suggestion for Amazon, I would post to their forums. Alternatively, you could write a simple program in Java which would add a timestamp corresponding to your last modified time to the file. After downloading back from Amazon you could run the app in reverse to retrieve that information. Hope this helps.

Comment: thought about that, but I just keep thinking it shouldn't be like that. As a data storage service AMZ shouldn't be touching file dates.